# Hide an external list on NewFormList

Tags: javascript

I have a list on my Sharepoint site called "Teams"

It has an external list called "Country"

How can I call "Country" to hide?

I have my JS on the new form working and I tried

```
document.getElementById("Country").style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way.  It works very well for form controls:

SP 2010 version:

```
function findcontrol(field) {
    var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("!");
    // get all comments
    for (var i=0;i < arr.length; i++ )
    {
        // now match the field name
        if (arr[i].innerHTML.indexOf(field) > 0)
        { 
            return arr[i]; 
        }
    }
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");

function hideFields() 
{
    var control = findcontrol("ControlToHideTitle");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
}
```

SP 2013 Version:

```
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("hideFields");

function findcontrol(field) {
    var arr = document.getElementById(field);
    return arr;
}

function hideFields() 
{
    var control = findcontrol("ControlToHideTitle");
    control.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.display="none";
}
```

This will hide everything on the NewItem.aspx for that control.  Give this a try.

Comment: Thank you very much! I use SP 2013 version and works? Now i want that appears depend the selection of another field. What can I do? CAML query?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
window.onload = function() {
     document.getElementById("Country").style.display = 'none';
};
```

Sometimes in sharepoint you'll find that YOUR javascript will run before THEIR page is fully loaded. So this is a workaround.

Comment: Works too! Thanks :) Now i want that appears depend the selection of another field. What can I do? CAML query?